# how to solve maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, django

The traceback:

```
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 3083, in signature
      return Signature.from_callabl`enter code here`e(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py"`enter code here`, li`enter code here`ne 2833, in from_callable
        follow_wrapper_chain`enter code here`s=follow_wrapped)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 2284, in _signature_from_callable
        return _signature_from_function(sigcls, obj)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 2154, in _signature_from_function
        kind=_POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD))
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/inspect.py", line 2469, in __init__
        self._kind = _ParameterKind(kind)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 310, in __call__
        return cls.__new__(cls, value)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/enum.py", line 530, in __new__
        if type(value) is cls:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from welcome import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('mysite.urls')),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>MyClub Event Calendar</h1>")
```

Comment: "from welcome import views", should this be in your base urls file?

Comment: Your question and code seems to have no relation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

Comment: Most of the time, if you hit the maximum recursion depth, it has one of two causes: you are using recursion where you should be using a loop, or you have a bug in your recursive function. Here, it's not clear what code is triggering the error in the first place.

Comment: Is the `urls.py` file you showed located in `mysite/urls.py` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check that **`include('mysite.urls'))`** points to *another file* (`urls.py` in ***another*** app), **not** this `urls.py` itself.

Comment: I was able to recreate the `RecursionError` by doing this.  So, this has to be the problem.